# Import from CSV into SQL Server 2005

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

The first day of month I will import from `test.csv` file information into my SQL Server 2005 database. I have this information in `test.csv` in the one column:

```
Receiver_number|Card_Number|Lname|purchase_date|tr_verif|station_name|prod_grp|product|unit_price|vol|amount|discount|sum_no_vat|vat|sum_with_vat|country|currency|milage|origin_amount|station_id
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1003680708|704487347252000033|3|2014-02-02T19:00:00|005375|IX Fortas|01|95 Miles|3.574|109.82|474.88|-35.78|392.46|82.42|510.66|LT|LTL||510.66|65059
1003680708|704487347252000034|3|2014-02-02T19:00:00|005375|IX Fortas|24|Cola|2.893|1.00|3.50|0|2.89|.61|3.50|LT|LTL||3.50|65059
```

Every value is separated by a `|` symbol.

How I can get it in SQL query?

I have used SSIS, I have tried convert to excel and changed regional settings in the computer but I could get this result in SQL Server 2005....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `bulk insert` like below

```
BULK INSERT <your_table>
    FROM '<your_path>\test.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',  
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\import_error.csv',
    TABLOCK
    )
```